# How to construct an APScheduler trigger class to pass to add_job?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using APScheduler and I need to add jobs with a programmatically  created list of trigger options.  That is, I can't write code where I pass trigger parameters directly to add_job (such as "second"="*/5" etc.).

The documentation mentions that you can create a trigger instance and pass that to add_job as the trigger parameter, instead of "cron" or "interval", etc.

I would like to try to do that, as it appears that the trigger constructor takes kwargs style parameters and I should be able to pass it a dictionary.

I have not found an example of how to do this.  I have tried:

```
from apscheduler.triggers import cron
# skipping irrelevant code

class Schedules(object):
    # skipping irrelevant code

    def add_schedule(self, new_schedule):
        # here I create trigger_args as {'second': '*/5'}, for example
        trigger = cron(trigger_args)
```

This fails with:  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
How do I instantiate a trigger object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my main problem without figuring out how to create a trigger instance (though I am still curious as to how to do that).

The main issue I had is that I need to programmatically create the trigger parameters.  Knowing a bit more now about parameter passing in python, I see that if I make a dict of *all* the parameters, not just the trigger parameters, I can pass the parameters this way:

job_def = {}
    #here I programmatically create the trigger parameters and add them to the dict

```
job_def["func"] = job_function
job_def["trigger"] = "cron"
job_def["args"] = [3]

new_job = self.scheduler.add_job(**job_def )
```